# How to store a created private key into Security KeyStore Android?

Tags: android, rsa, keystore

I have followed this below code that I need to generate a keypair stored in KeyStore

```
// generate a key pair
Context ctx = getContext();
Calendar notBefore = Calendar.getInstance()
Calendar notAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
notAfter.add(1, Calendar.YEAR);
KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(ctx)
            .setAlias("key1")
            .setSubject(
                    new X500Principal(String.format("CN=%s, OU=%s", alais,
                            ctx.getPackageName())))
            .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE).setStartDate(notBefore.getTime())
            .setEndDate(notAfter.getTime()).build();

KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
KeyPair kp = kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

By this way, my keypair is generated and stored into Keystore but when calling this function: `getPrivateKey.encoded()` , it will return a null bytes array.

My will is I want generate normally, I can get both PrivateKey and PublicKey Encode (This is my own purpose). Then I want to store them into KeyStore to keep secret.

I have tried this: keyStore.setEntry(alias, privateKey, cert) but I got exception due to wrong params maybe. I don't understand what certificate I should get from?
I really appreciate your comments